# How to do the below

Tags: java, android, json

I have a java class called JobModel, it implements the interface IModel.  This model contains one item.

```
public interface IModel<T> { T Instantiate(JSONObject o); }
```

The referenced function looks like this in the JobModel Class.

```
public IModel<JobModel> Instantiate(JSONObject o) {
    JobModel j = new JobModel();

    try {
        j.setID(o.getInt("ID"));
        j.setName(o.getString("Name"));
        j.setDescription(o.getString("Description"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return j;
}
```

I have a controller called BaseController which takes a Generic Type.  This controller implements IOnAsyncResult and IController.  Both of these are custom interfaces that I have setup.

What I am trying to do is implement a framework that allows me to hook into a process for calling APIs that I have I have the below implementation.

Here is the function that is called from the API AsyncTask Class

```
public void onResultSuccess(int resultCode, JSONArray results) {
    ProcessJsonArray(results);

    try { if (this.viewDelegate != null) this.viewDelegate.InterfaceUpdate(list); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

The JSON Array is processed in the ProcessJsonArray function, which is:

```
public void ProcessJsonArray(JSONArray a) {
    for (int i=0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        try { list.add(this.ProcessJsonObject(a.getJSONObject(i))); }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

The individual JSON Objects are processed in ProcessJsonObject, which is:

```
public IModel<T> ProcessJsonObject(JSONObject o) {
    return model.Instantiate(o);
}
```

The model field is a class field that is instantiated in the constructor of the Controller, specifical the controller that extends the base controller class.

This all works fine, except, the model, list, and resultsList are setup this way:

```
public ArrayList<IModel<T>> list;
public ArrayList<IModel<T>> resultsList;
public IModel<T> model;
```

I find the challenge when I try to work with any of the properties.   For example, when I try to iterate through the list property when it is setup with the Job Controller, I am unable to access the Getter and Setter functions of the job Model.  The iteration is setup as follows:

```
for (IModel<JobModel> j : list) {
    if (j.getName().contains(Value)) { addToResultsList(j); }
    //Additional else/if statements removed for bravity.  
}
```

How do you access the Getter/Setter functions for the current setup, or what is the proper setup to accomplish a loosely couple framework like this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this post didn't spark any discussion, I figured I would post what I did to work around the situation.

The primary problem was accessing the Getters and Setters of the model class.  So, I moved the IModel from the defined properties (both the single objects and list objects).

Also removed the IModel implementation from each model, that allowed me to declare the Instantiation function as static.

Then I implemented this private function in my Base Controller Class.

```
private Object ReturnPopulatedModelObject(JSONObject o)
{
    if (model instanceof PersonModel) { return PersonModel.Instantiate(o); }
    else if (model instanceof ContactModel) { return ContactModel.Instantiate(o); }
    else if (model instanceof ContactTypeModel) { return ContactTypeModel.Instantiate(o); }
    else if (model instanceof JobModel) { return JobModel.Instantiate(o); }
    else { throw new IllegalStateException("The Model is defined as something other than predefined!  The Model is defined as " + model.getClass().getName() + "."); }
}
```

This way, allowed me to call the Instantiate function of the specific model types.  The only thing to consider is that you have to cast the returning value in the calling function to the generic type, as such:

```
public T ProcessJsonObject(JSONObject o) {
    return (T)ReturnPopulatedModelObject(o);
}
```

Hope this helps for a person who might stumble upon this.